# Iteraciones en sql server para calcular acumulado

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta que me muestra el listado de facturas por cliente, la fecha de la factura y su valor pagado (las fechas están ordenadas de la más antigua a la más reciente). Quisiera saber si es posible obtener otra columna donde se calcule para cada fila el acumulado del total pagado contando el valor de esa factura hasta el valor de la factura con fecha de 10 días hacia delante o hacia atrás.

Este es mi código actual:

```
SELECT OINV.DocNum
  , OINV.CardCode
  , OINV.CardName
  , FORMAT(OINV.TaxDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') 'TaxDate'
  , OINV.PaidSum
FROM OINV
WHERE
OINV.PaidSum > 0
AND OINV.DocStatus = 'C'
AND OINV.ExtraDays > 0
ORDER BY OINV.CardCode, OINV.DocNum
```

Y me arroja lo siguiente: Lo que quiero agregar es lo que indico en la columna `Acumulado`.

```
DocNum  CardCode TaxDate     PaidSum     Acumulado
------- -------- ----------  --------    ---------
447892  C3333    5/05/2021   487141.13  2075278.4 ----> Este sería el acumulado de la primera factura ya que toma del 5/05/2021 hasta 15/05/2021 porque no sobrepasa los 10 días
448672  C3333    12/05/2021  1039709.77 5756890.64 --> para la siguiente fila, sería la sumatoria de la factura hasta el valor de la factura que no supere los 10 días, es decir, acumulado desde el 12/05/2021 hasta 22/05/2021  
449139  C3333    15/05/2021  548427.5 --> y así sucesivamente para cada factura
449578  C3333    19/05/2021  1778170.86
449579  C3333    19/05/2021  135820.65
449722  C3333    20/05/2021  1883140
449941  C3333    22/05/2021  371621.86
450438  C3333    26/05/2021  1303151.88
450788  C3333    29/05/2021  963277.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer usando el operador APPLY para hacer una especie de JOIN a la misma tabla que contenga las fechas requeridas. Dejo un ejemplo con datos de prueba.

```
-- Estos son datos de prueba
DECLARE @Prueba TABLE (
    DocNum  int,
    CardCode varchar(10),
    TaxDate  date,   
    PaidSum     float,
    Acumulado   float);
INSERT INTO @Prueba VALUES
( 447892, 'C3333', '20210505',  487141.13 , 2075278.4 ),
( 448672, 'C3333', '20210512',  1039709.77, 5756890.64),
( 449139, 'C3333', '20210515',  548427.5  , NULL      ),
( 449578, 'C3333', '20210519',  1778170.86, NULL      ),
( 449579, 'C3333', '20210519',  135820.65 , NULL      ),
( 449722, 'C3333', '20210520',  1883140   , NULL      ),
( 449941, 'C3333', '20210522',  371621.86 , NULL      ),
( 450438, 'C3333', '20210526',  1303151.88, NULL      ),
( 450788, 'C3333', '20210529',  963277.5  , NULL      );

-- Esta es la solución
SELECT *
FROM @Prueba p
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT SUM( PAidSum) AS Acumulado
            FROM @Prueba sp
            WHERE sp.CardCode = p.CardCode
            AND sp.TaxDate BETWEEN DATEADD( dd, -10, p.TaxDate) 
                           AND     DATEADD( dd,  10, p.TaxDate))s;
```

Comment: Gracias Luis, la cuestión es que el acumulado debe ir desde cada fila hacia abajo hasta donde aplique el rango de días, y me está calculando el acumulado sumando también el valor de la fila de arriba.
Para darte una idea, el primer acumulado va desde la fila 1 hasta la fila 3 porque rango de la fecha de la fila 1 hasta la fecha de la fila 3 no superan los 10 días (entonces aquí se sumarian los paidsum de esas 3 filas.
Y en el caso de la última fila el acumulado sería el mismo valor ya que no tiene filas hacia abajo.

Comment: Necesito que aclares bien como funciona el acumulado porque en la pregunta principal mencionas que son 10 días hacia adelante y hacia atrás.

Comment: yo quiero que se evalúe las fechas de cada fila con las sigtes, es decir, la fecha de la primera fila se evalúa con la fecha de la 2da y si la diferencia de las dos es menor a 10 dias entonces que vaya sumando el paidsum (o sea el paidsum de la 1ra fila + paidsum 2da fila), luego se sigue comparando la 1ra fecha con la fecha de la 3ra fila y si la diferencia de las dos es menor a 10, que también sume su paidsum (paidsum 1ra fila+paidsum 2da fila+paidsum 3ra fila) hasta que la diferencia supere los 10 dias dejará de sumar, este total iría en el acumulado de la 1ra fila

Comment: Luego empezaría a hacer lo mismo desde la segunda fila evaluando con las filas de abajo y así sucesivamente hasta la última fila, por eso para la última fila el acumulado sería el mismo paidsum de la fila porque no tiene con quién evaluar más hacia abajo.

Es complicado explicarlo, espero se entienda mejor.